# Switching Orders of Differentiation and Integration in case of Function of 2 Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I encountered the following equation in my calculus lecture notes:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xf(x,y)dy = f(x,x)+\int_0^x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)dy
$$
Could you show me how to prove the above equality?

Answer (score 0):

This is a particular version of what is known as  the [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Proofs). The wikipedia link provides a nice proof of the general case(s), and it is not too hard to see how this particular form follows